# (C++) Is there a way to create different matrices in a loop?

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm writing a code that reads a text file to create a matrix dinamically. I will then get the information from this matrix to write it in another text file.

I put in a 'for' loop that will create a matrix for each chunk of text that it reads, here it is:

```
    for (cont = 0; cont < nPares; cont++){
        
        ResultFile >> FlowOri;
        ResultFile >> FlowDest;
        ResultFile >> nPaths;
        ResultFile >> largestPath;

        double** iPathMatrix = (double**) new double[nPaths];
        for (i = 0; i < nPaths; i++) {
            iPathMatrix[i] = (double*) new double[largestPath + 2];
        }

        for (i = 0; i < nPaths; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < largestPath + 2; j++) {
                ResultFile >> iPathMatrix[i][j];
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < nPaths; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < largestPath + 2; j++) {
                cout << iPathMatrix[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << "\n";
        }

        free(iPathMatrix);
    }
```

'ResultFile' is an ifstream.
That 'cout' near the end was put there to check if it was creating the matrices as intended, which it is.

As you can see, I'm creating the matrix and then freeing the memory at the end of the loop to create it again, since it will have the same name. I can probably figure a way to work with this, but it'd be way easier if I could create a different matrix with each loop, perhaps naming each with the 'FlowOri' and 'FlowDest' variables, if that's possible, and after the loop stops, access them and write in my output file.

Is there a way to do it? How would I reference it afterwards?

Comment: When you remove the unnecessary casts in front of the `new`, you will get an error for the first one. It should be `new double*[nPaths];`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable names only have a meaning for the programmer and disappear from the executable unless you use a debug mode, so C++ does not allow to create *dynamically named* variables. Anyway even with languages that allow it, it is a terrible design.

But you can always create an array (or better a vector) of any object type. So if you want to store everything in the loop and process later the whole data, you could use a 3 level vector. With the magic of references, little has to be changed from your code:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>> matrixes(nPares);
for (auto& iPathMatrix : matrixes) {    // iPathMatrix is a reference inside matrixes
    ResultFile >> FlowOri;
    ResultFile >> FlowDest;
    ResultFile >> nPaths;
    ResultFile >> largestPath;

    iPathMatrix = std::vector<std::vector<double>>(nPaths);
    for (i = 0; i < nPaths; i++) {
        iPathMatrix[i] = std::vector<double>(largestPath + 2];
    }

    for (i = 0; i < nPaths; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < largestPath + 2; j++) {
            ResultFile >> iPathMatrix[i][j];
        }
    }

}
// control:
for (int i = 0; i < nPares; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matrixes[i].size(); j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < matrixes[i][j].size(); k++) {
            std::cout << matrixes[i][j][k] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

`matrixes` now contain all of your data

Comment: This worked perfectly and it was easy to implement, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

> As you can see, I'm creating the matrix and then freeing the memory at
> the end of the loop to create it again,

No you aren't (at least not correctly). Each new[] must be paired with a delete[], so the correct code is

```
   for (i = 0; i < nPaths; i++) {
        delete[] iPathMatrix[i];
   }
   delete[] iPathMatrix;
```

Now since you are programming C++, you could avoid this by using vectors.

```
   std::vector<std::vector<double>> iPathMatrix(nPaths, std::vector<double>(largestPath + 2));
```

Now you don't need to allocate or free anything, but the rest of your code is unchanged.

Now as for your actual question. If I understand it correctly you want to associate a matrix with the value of the `flowOri` variable. That's easy to do, you should use a `std::map`.

You haven't said what type `flowOri` is, I'm going to assume it's a `std::string` but you should be able to get this to work whatever type it is.

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>

// lets give a shorter name for the vector type
using MatrixRowType = std::vector<double>;
using MatrixType = std::vector<MatrixRowType>;

// and this is the map type that holds the matrices
using MatrixMapType = std::map<std::string, MatrixType>;

...

MatrixMapType matrixMap;
for (cont = 0; cont < nPares; cont++){
    // read stuff
    ResultFile >> FlowOri;
    ...
    // read the matrix
    MatrixType iPathMatrix(nPaths, MatrixRowType(largestPath + 2));
    ...
    // save the matrix in the map keyed by FlowOri
    matrixMap[FlowOri] = iPathMatrix;
}
```

Now later when you want to retrieve a matirx you just write `matrixMap[something]` where `something` is a variable with the name of the matrix you want to retrieve.

Comment: perhaps move `iPathMatrix` into the map?

Comment: @Caleth Good point but I'm trying to keep it simple, the OP has presumably never used a map before, so one new concept at a time.

Comment: FlowOri and Flow Dest are both int variables, I forgot to mention that, sorry. Yeah, I have never used a map, and I haven't been programming on C++ for too long, I'm kinda picking it up as I go because my tutor put me in this project which is using it.

This sounds like it could work, I'll look up some material about maps and give it a shot. Will give feedback when I test it, thanks.

Comment: I tested the other answer first  because it looked easier to implement and it worked perfectly. I reckon I kinda misled you because I realized I didn't need to use the 'FlowOri' variable or any other to reference it afterwards, so sorry for that.

Even so, this is another tool I'll look into, so thanks for that!